# How to make an overlay popup window on magento 1.9.2.3?

Tags: magento-1.9, template, popup

I was wondering if you could help me with the code that i should paste on **promotion template** in order to make a **overlay popup window**? I need to make a popup window come up when a customer puts a specific product to the cart (to let him know that if he buys an extra item, he will get a discount). 
Thank you very much in advance,
Anna

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there is an Amasty extension that provides functionality similar to what you describe: [Free Gift with Purchase](https://amasty.com/magento-free-gift.html).

If you cannot find an extension that suits your needs, doing this manually is definitely feasible.

- Detect that product was added to the cart. 1) Use an Observer event, or 2) inspect cart on page load with jQuery (this is not standard).
- Reveal a template of your choice. For example, templates/custompopup/popup.phtml. Include it in the page with layout XML, or potentially your Observer could add the block programmatically.